# Installing vulkun on Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: drivers, nvidia, vulkan

I have installed vulkan on ubuntu server following [this](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/latest/linux/getting_started_ubuntu.html). However, when I run `vulkaninfo` I get

```
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : loader_icd_scan: Can not find 'ICD' object in ICD JSON file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_layers.json.  Skipping ICD JSON
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : loader_scanned_icd_add: Could not get 'vkCreateInstance' via 'vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr' for ICD libGLX_nvidia.so.0
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : vkCreateInstance: Found no drivers!
Cannot create Vulkan instance.
This problem is often caused by a faulty installation of the Vulkan driver or attempting to use a GPU that does not support Vulkan.
ERROR at /build/vulkan-tools-1.3.224.0~rc2-1lunarg18.04/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:672:vkCreateInstance failed with ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
```

output of `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   43C    P8    16W /  70W |      2MiB / 15360MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvidia_layers.json` should not be in `/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d`.  That JSON file describes a layer, not a driver.  It belongs in `/usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d`.  But it does look like the loader is finding an ICD because it tried to load a function address from `libGLX.nvidia.so`, which is the driver.  It looks like a bad driver installation or someone moved the JSON files around.  I would proceed by moving `nvidia_layers.json` to the `implicit_layer.d` directory and see if that helps, in case the loader is getting confused somehow by that file being in `icd.d`.  Aside from that, try a driver reinstall and make sure you have the latest Vulkan loader.  Finally, if the problem persists, you may get better traction filing an issue at the [loader GitHub](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader).

Comment: Thanks, it was probably bad driver installation. purged and reinstalled and that worked.